# Cash out virtual credit with PayPal API

Tags: php, api, flutter, paypal, laravel-7

I'm currently working on a mobile app as well as the API to transit data through this app and my databases.
We chose to use Paypal to make payments.

To summarize, we offer credit packs at the beginning, where 1 euro = 5 credits. No problem to implement the packs payment alone, but the only problem is whether there is an API, or another way to convert its credits into real money, and then make some kind of transfer from our Paypal account to a bank account or something.

I saw that there was a service called **Hyperwallet**, developed by Paypal, but I wanted to know if it is possible before anything else.

I want to point out that the application is developed in Flutter and the API in Laravel (why Laravel? Simply because there is a back office that also turns on it... a stone two strokes)

Thank you in advance for your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to send money from your PayPal account to users, you can use  [PayPal Payouts](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/payouts/integrate/prerequisites/#get-access-to-paypal-payouts). First you have to request and get approval there, and then you can use its API or upload a spreadsheet to send money from your account to anyone with an email address.